# Не могу разобраться почему не работает как должно

Tags: java

делаю по учебнику хеад фирст андроид -буквально первая же программа.
должна на выбор вида пива после клика по кнопке выдавать нужный сорт.
текст изменил под свои реалии.Вместо нужной строчки всегда выдаёт вторую

```
else {
   brands.add("Слишком сложно");
   brands.add("Давай еще раз");




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


public void onClick123(View view) {
    TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
    Spinner color = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.color);
    String beerType = String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItemId()); 
    List<String> brandsList = expert.getBrands(beerType);
    StringBuilder brandsFormatted =new  StringBuilder();
    for (String brand : brandsList){
            brandsFormatted.append(brand).append("\n");}
    brands.setText(brandsFormatted);
 }
}
```

второй активити

```
 List<String> getBrands(String color) {
    List<String> brands =new ArrayList<>();
      if (color.equals("тупые все вокруг?")){
          brands.add("Нет,это ты тупой");
          brands.add("Попробуй еще раз");}
      else {
          brands.add("Слишком сложно");
          brands.add("Давай еще раз");}
      return brands;
```

```js
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:entries="@array/SpinnerText"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/color"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/color"
        android:layout_below="@id/color"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/but"
        android:onClick="onClick123"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brands"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/brands"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">beershow</string>
<string name="but">Не тупи,Жми сюда</string>
<string name="brands">Это не сложно,тут всего одна кнопка</string>
<string-array name="SpinnerText">
    <item>ты тупой?</item>
    <item>тупые все вокруг?</item>
    <item>ни кто не тупой?</item>
    <item>сам ты тупой!</item>
    <item>сколько можно одно и тоже. </item>

</string-array>
```

стрингс и актвиити мейн тоже прикрепил

Comment: Интересный метод onClick123(), не уж то в книге так учат:)

Comment: ну там имя не играет же роли)